# BracketHighlighter in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know vs code can highlight brackets when the cursor next to it but that's not what I'm looking for. I want it to auto detect the scope like sublime does. The cursor can be anywhere inside of the brackets and it detects which scope it's in. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks.(There's an image I attached here) [Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5NOL.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight enclosing bracket in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182543/highlight-enclosing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything like you want.  But the [expand-region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region) extension is pretty slick and will hot-key to ever expanding scopes.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful!

Comment: @TheMic58 - Really? The link is for a Sublime Text extension, not VS Code.

Comment: I fixed the link -- really I did.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that might be what you are looking for, it is similar to BracketHighlighter in Sublime Text 3.

Search for 'VSCode Highlight Matching Tag' in the Extensions(Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + X) inside VS Code.

Hope it helps.

https://github.com/vincaslt/vscode-highlight-matching-tag