# Highlight enclosing bracket in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to highlight brackets when the cursor is anywhere within the enclosing brackets? Default settings highlight it only when I place the cursor near the brackets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is now a way by default, [in VSCode 1.40 (October 2019)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_improvements-to-bracket-matching):

> ### Improvements to bracket matching
>
> Previously, VS Code would only highlight matching brackets when the cursor was next to a bracket character.
> **Now VS Code will always highlight enclosing brackets if they exist**.

[image: Image showing highlighted enclosing brackets]

> We have also adjusted our `Go to Bracket` and `Select to Bracket` actions to use enclosing brackets.

It is improved and supported natively with [VSCode 1.60 (Aug. 2021)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization):

> Bracket pair colorization can be enabled by setting `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true`.
> All colors are themeable and up to six colors can be configured.
>
> [image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_60/bracket-pair-colorization-checker_ts.gif]

Comment: How/where do we set "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled":true? I copied above and put it at the command line in vscode, and had error, "unexpected token :"

Comment: @Michele You can use Ctr+, to open the user settings, and type `bracketPairColorization`: click on the checkbox, and you are good to go!

Answer (score 3):

VS Code only supports [bracket matching](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_bracket-matching) when the cursor is near the opening or closing bracket.  Maybe an extension would help highlight the enclosing brackets wherever you are in the code but I haven't been able to find one.

If you just want to quickly find matching brackets, braces, parens, etc. you could try [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer) or [Rainbow Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets).

Answer (score 3):

With [release 1.60 (September 2021)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization), VS Code now has bracket pair colorization built in, indicating all matching brackets by color.

This feature can be enabled by adding this line to settings.json:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
```

[image: bracket pair colorization]

Comment: Good point. I had mentioned it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69009005/6309, but forgot to update my old answer on this page. I have done so now.

Answer (score 3):

Also maybe you will like VSCode extension "Blockman", it highlights nested code blocks. (I am the author of Blockman)

[image: VSCode Blockman intro]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Version: 1.63.2(MacOS). Default bracket highlight feature was not working for me. In case, someone face similar issue, set it true.

```
"editor.matchBrackets": true,
```