# How Do I Change Comma and Bracket Colors in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sounds kinda of dumb, but I  can't figure out how to target this type of text. What is the command to change the color of commas, quotes, brackets, etc in VS Code 1.5?

Thanks a lot

Comment: bracket question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57764284/11107541

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "punctuation",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#ffffff"
        }
    }]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html

Answer (score 12):

For brackets specifically, See VSCode 1.60, Aug. 2021, which includes bracket pair colorization as a built in feature.

> ### [High performance bracket pair colorization](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization)
>
> The editor now supports native bracket pair colorization:
>
> [image: Side by side comparison with bracket pair colorization on and off]
>
> Bracket pair colorization can be enabled by setting "**editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true**.
> All colors are themeable and up to six colors can be configured.
>
> We implemented this feature to address performance issues of the famous [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) extension by [CoenraadS](https://github.com/CoenraadS).

Settings:

```json
 colorCustomizations:

{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#3700ff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#66ff00",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly change these colors (at least not easily) but you have a few options:

**Pick a built in theme**

Hit `(Ctrl|Cmd) + K, T` to open "Preferences: Color Theme" and select one one of the options, if you use the arrow keys to select the option it will give you a preview of the theme.

**Install a marketplace theme**

Press `(Ctrl|Cmd) + Shift + X` to open the extensions sidebar then enter `category:themes` if you select one of these results a readme will be displayed which will usually contain a screenshot.

Once you find one you like click install, then click reload. Once reloaded the theme or themes will be selectable through the "Preferences: Color Theme" command as detailed above

**Install any TextMate theme**

VSCode uses textmate themes of which there are many community shared ones available, [see here](http://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/themes/#adding-a-new-theme)

**Create your own**

You are also free to make your own TextMate themes, but they look rather complex and are probably more hassle than it is worth to just modify a few colors, you can find useful guides and even helpful tools with some quick google searches if this is what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

First set Bracket pair colorization off `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false`
then set the color you want.

```json
            {
                "scope": [
                    "punctuation.brackets.curly",
                    "punctuation.brackets.round",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#f1bff4",
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            },
```