# How do I change the foreground colour of brackets in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change my bracket colors separately,
for example:

```
() -> yellow  
{} -> yellow
[] -> purple
```

How can I do it? I couldn't find the correct codes for them.

Comment: For which language(s)?

Comment: Sorry for being late I had to go. I'm working with Python

Comment: dear reader, **1)** if you're interested in colouring **_matching bracket highlighting**_, see [How can I customize the highlighting of matching bracket/brace/parenthesis pairs in VS Code?](/q/39188214/11107541) **2)** if you're interested in customizing colours of **bracket _guides_**, see [How to change indent guide line color between brackets in VS Code?](/q/47942390/11107541).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the VS Code plugin, [`CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer)

It has the customize option to set custom color for each pair.

Comment: Can you make it so `(`s are always yellow no matter in what order they appear?  It would be helpful if you showed how to do it, rather than just a link.

Answer (score 47):

Vs Code now has this built-in in Stable v1.60.0. It should provide more performant built-in functionality.

Check this setting (the default is `enabled`):  `Editor > Bracket Pair Colorization: Enabled`

Then in your settings `colorCustomizations`:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#3700ff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#66ff00",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000",
  }
}
```

There are currently up to 6 bracket colors that can be set `editorBracketHighlight.foreground`1,2,3,4,5,6

This may change as this is a work in progress.

I especially like `"editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000"` so if vscode finds an "unexpected" bracket, like an extra bracket, it will color it red.

See more at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#high-performant-bracket-pair-colorization:

> Bracket pair colorization can be enabled by setting
> `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true`. All colors are
> themeable and up to six colors can be configured.
>
> We implemented this feature to address performance issues of the
> famous Bracket Pair Colorizer extension by CoenraadS. Now, even
> changes in huge documents are reflected immediately:

Comment: how can we apply text-shadow to produce a glow effect ? thanks

Comment: My files now look crazy colorful, I'm not really a fan. I do want the red 'unexpectedBracket' so I've kept it on but set all 6 colors to '#fff'.

Comment: As helpful as this answer is to most people, I think OP is looking for a solution which colors a certain bracket type (curly, square, etc.) with a specific color, no matter how they are ordered or nested.

Answer (score 19):

As of [version 1.60](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60) VS Code supports native bracket pair colorization.

You can enable this setting by going to

*File -> Preferences -> Settings*

Search for “bracket colorization” and enable the **Bracket Pair Colorization** option.

Or, you can add `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true` in `settings.json` file.

All colors are themeable and you can configure up to six colors.

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#B48EAD",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#A3BE8C",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#EBCB8B",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#D08770",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#BF616A",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#abb2c0",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#db6165"
},
```

[Source](https://neutrondev.com/vs-code-native-bracket-pair-colorization/)

Answer (score 12):

Install Bracket Pair Colorizer:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer

Then change bracketPairColorizer.colorMode to Independent, so you can set up a color to a bracket. Document says "Independent brackets allow each bracket type to use its own color pool".

```
    "bracketPairColorizer.colorMode": "Independent",
```

And config your colors in bracketPairColorizer.independentPairColors:

```
    "bracketPairColorizer.independentPairColors": [
        [
          "()",
          [
            "Yellow"
          ],
          "Red" // use when right bracket is missing
        ],
        [
          "[]",
          [
            "Purple"
          ],
          "Red"
        ],
        [
          "{}",
          [
            "Blue"
          ],
          "Red"
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 5):

From August 2021 [(version 1.60)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization) VS Code has native Native Bracket Pair Colourization support, according to release notes it is **10,000x faster** than [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer) extension.

The feature can be enabled by adding the setting `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true` in settings.json

Answer (score 1):

Newer version of Bracket Pair Colorizer is faster and better.

[Bracket Pair Colorizer 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) by the same author.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using settings.json

```
editor.tokenColorCustomizations
```

Something like this

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "punctuation",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#ffffff"
        }
    }]
}
```

You can also view this blog

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/theming#textmate-theme-rules

And use this extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer

Comment: I don't believe this is what the OP wants.  He wants `()` to always be yellow, for example, and `[]` purple say.  `Punctuation` is too broad a scope to differentiate between these.

Comment: I tried this one but it changes all punctuations. I have searched a lot but I couldn't find how to change colors separately.

Answer (score 0):

Both v1 and v2 of Bracket pair colorizer are [slow](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2/issues/241) and now [abandoned](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2). A leaner alternative is [Rainbow brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets).

Comment: Just for information, are you the developer of Rainbow Brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Recommended configuration and a great color scheme (in settings.json):
Configuration ⬇:

```
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colorMode": "Consecutive",
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.forceUniqueOpeningColor": true,
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.forceIterationColorCycle": true,
```

Great color scheme ⬇:

```
  "bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors": [
    "#ffff00",
    "rgba(0,250,255)",
    "#ec5f67", // fade red
    "#66ff00", // bright green
    "#FFD700", // bright yellow
    "#FB7A24", // bright orange
    "Orchid"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do depends on whether you have bracket pair colourization enabled, and if you don't, on a per-language-basis by what [syntax highlighting mechanism](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) (semantic or TextMate-based) is being used by the language support extension you're using for that language mode.

Note that a language support extension can use a mixture of semantic and TextMate-based highlighting, and can choose to either highlight brackets with one or the other.

The supported colour formats include `"#RGB"` (red, green, blue in hex), `"#RGBA"` (added "alpha" (transparency/opacity)), `"#RRGGBB"` (more resolution), `"#RRGGBBAA"`.

#### With bracket pair colourization enabled

If you have enabled bracket pair colourization (`editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled`), then use the following:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ff0000",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#ff0000",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#ff0000",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#ff0000",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#ff0000",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#ff0000",
}
```

If you want some degree of independence of different bracket pair characters/types, use the `editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType` setting.

Note also that language support extensions can configure which bracket pair types take part in bracket pair colourization in their config settings (the `colorizedBracketPairs` property (Ex. [the builtin TypeScript extension does this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/typescript-basics/language-configuration.json))), and you can also override that in your settings by using the `editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs` setting (probably you want to do it as a [language override setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)).

#### When using a language support extension's syntax highlighting

Note that whether semantic highlighting is used or not can also depend on whether the current colour theme you're using opts-in to it by default, though you can force it to be enabled. For more info, see [the docs on "Enablement of Semantic Highlighting"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#enablement-of-semantic-highlighting).

Open [the Scope Inspector tool](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) by running the command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Move the cursor to go on/before the bracket character of interest, and see what it says in the section "textmate scopes" or "semantic token type".

If semantic highlighting is being used and taking effect, you should take note of what the semantic token's name is open settings.json and edit the `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations`. Triggering suggestions will be your friend here. An example of what this might look like is this:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name Here]": { // remove this wrapper to apply regarless of current colour theme
        "rules": {
            "parenthesis": "#ff0000", // can add language specifier like "parenthesis:javascript" to any of these
            "bracket": "#ff0000",
            "curlybrace": { // can also use this expanded form
                "foreground": "#ff0000",
                // "fontStyle": 
                // "bold": false,
                // "italic": false,
                // "strikethrough": false,
                // "underline": false,
            },
        },
    },
},
```

If TextMate-based syntax highlighting is being used and taking effect, then you should instead put the TextMate token into the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting. For example:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name Here]": { // remove this wrapper to apply regarless of current colour theme
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "punctuation.definition.array.begin.json.comments, punctuation.definition.array.end.json.comments, punctuation.definition.dictionary.begin.json.comments, punctuation.definition.dictionary.end.json.comments",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                // "fontStyle": "",
            },
        }],
    },
},
```

If you want some degree of independence of different bracket pair characters/types but the semantic tokens or TextMate tokens/grammar provided by the language support extension you are using doesn't differentiate different bracket types into giving them their own separate tokens, then you're out of luck. Either ask your extension's maintainer nicely in a feature-request on their issue tracker, or look for another extension that does that.