# Changing the colour of curley braces inside VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

I write content in VSC and I use handlebars to write content.

```
{{#jan}} Hello my name is Tony {{else}} Hi my name is Bob {{/if}}
```

Is there any way I can get the content inside the `{{}}` to highlight something like bright yellow? when I have loads of these in the docs, its hard to spot them when scrolling.

I've tried messing around with the workspace settings.js file but have had no luck. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68885221/836330 This will soon be built-in to vscode - bracket pair colorization that is.  For handlebars styles brackets `{{stuff}}` it is currently coloring both pairs the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of your question asks how to change the color of the brackets themselves, while the body asks for how to change the content in the middle.

here's a solution for the title part: the extension bracket pair colorizer will give you full control over curly brace colors.  by default, it colors nested braces differently, but as per its documentation, you can configure it however you want. so if you choose only one brace color, they can both be yellow or whatever color you want

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2

Comment: That's nice. Are most of these Extensions written in Typescript? i'm trying to write my own but i'm just starting to learn Javascript

Comment: Glad it helped - if it solved your problem, you can click the check mark at the left so other people visiting see it was a solution.  You can see the source code of most extensions by visiting their GitHub page - that's a good place to start learning how to make one.