# Assigning different color pool to each bracket type in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, customization, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to assign a different color pool to each bracket type in Visual Studio Code?

There is a JSON parameter `"independentColorPoolPerBracketType"` that changes the bracket syntax highlighting to follow indentation level AND bracket type, instead of just indentation level. For example, `"([()])"` is by default highlighted as "gold-purple-blue-blue-purple-gold", but with this setting on, it changes to "gold-gold-purple-purple-gold-gold".

Using the `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` setting, I can change these colors, but only "globally", meaning it modifies the color pool of all bracket types simultaneously. If I, for example want the square bracket to have its very own color that the round bracket won't have, this setting won't be able to provide that for me.

Is there a way to change the color pool of each bracket type independently?

Comment: so you don't want multiple levels of square brackets to have different colours based on nesting level? you just want each bracket type to have its own _single_ colour? because if so, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57764284/11107541 (see the second half of [my answer post there](/a/77682398/11107541))

Comment: this might otherwise be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74312066/11107541