# How to set Independent Color Pool Per Bracket Type

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to set Independent Color Pool Per Bracket Type

before [#159995](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159995) this feature is not working properly

but I found in [#131027](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131027) the 1st level of () [] and {} use the same color

I want to use Independent Color Pool Per Bracket Type

for example, () are different reds, [] are different blues and {} are different greens

How to set them?

Comment: So instead of coloring based on level/nesting, you want to color them based on type?

Comment: based on both level and type. For example, on extension Rainbow Brackets (by 2gua) I can modify `~/.vscode/extensions/2gua.rainbow-brackets-0.0.6/out/src/extension.js` and change `var roundBracketsColor`, `var squareBracketsColor`, `var squigglyBracketsColor`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, that's just not how that setting/feature works. It just makes VS Code keep track of the nesting level for each bracket type independently / separately. They still end up using the same values specified by the `editorBracketHighlight.foreground*` colour customizations.

If you're interested in the history of the addition of that feature/setting, see [[Feature Request] Bracket Pair Colorization: Consecutive/independent color mode #131027](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131027).

You could raise a feature request of your own, but this sounds complicated. What bracket pairs are defined and which ones participate in bracket pair colourization depends on the language support extension's configuration and is overridable via the `editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs` setting. I'm not sure how exactly this would fit into the framework of the `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.