# Syntax error on iter_content (requests module)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

New to this, so apologies. I am trying to download some files using the requests module in Python (3.7), and getting a syntax error on the *iter_content*, and I cannot work out why. Drawing lots from Automate the Boring Stuff. Here is the relevant block:

```
# Collecting a list of the relevant lecture files to download:
lectureList = []
for item in elems:
    if '/lectures/esm' in str(item):
        urlIWant = item.get('href')
        finalUrl = 'https://nworbmot.org/courses/esm-2020' + urlIWant[1:]
        lectureList.append(finalUrl)


# Download lecture PDFs to 'Lectures' folder
os.makedirs('Lectures', exist_ok = True)
print('Downloading Lecture Files...')
for lectureUrl in lectureList:
    res = requests.get(lectureUrl)
    print(f'Dowloading file: {lectureUrl}')
    res.raise_for_status()
    downloadFile = open(os.path.join('Lectures', os.path.basename(lectureUrl), 'wb')
    for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=10000): #This is the line that gets the syntax error
        downloadFile.write(chunk)
    downloadFile.close()
    print('Done')
```

It is the fourth from last line that that is throwing the error. I have tried removing and changing chunk_size, indentations, checked typos. Clearly missing something... thanks.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis after `lectureURL`. There should be 2

Comment: Thank you. All working perfectly! Any tips on how to keep track of parentheses?

Comment: Tools like VSCode can help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182543/highlight-enclosing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code